Difference between `tx.gasprice`, `assembly { gasPrice := gasprice() }` and `block.basefee`
I created the following contract and deployed on Sepolia, including an inline assembly call which returns gas price for the transaction.
The question is how and why does the ... := gasprice() output different from tx.gasprice and block.basefee?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract GasAnalyser {

uint256 public baseFee;
uint256 public gasPrice;
uint256 public gasPriceCheck;

function getBaseFee() public {
    baseFee = block.basefee;
}

function getGasPrice() public {
    gasPrice = tx.gasprice;
}

function getGasPriceCheck() public {
    uint256 check;
    assembly {
        check := gasprice()
     }
    gasPriceCheck = check;
}

}

NOTE
The following outputs are written for the 3 functions, respectively (of course, we can expect them to change on each call, but the difference between them remains the interesting factor):

getBaseFee uint256: 9138656943
getGasPrice uint256: 10950129256
getGasPriceCheck uint256: 11056634983



getBaseFee function: In this block.basefee is used, which is the minimum amount of gas price required to include a transaction in the block, set by the network itself and dependent on network congestion.

getGasPrice function: In this tx.gasprice is used, which is the total gas price the sender was willing to pay for this specific transaction. This is the max fee per gas set by the user in their wallet or transaction configuration.
The effective gas price for a transaction can differ from block.basefee due to the additional priority fee (also called "tip").
tx.gasprice = block.basefee + priority fee.

getGasPriceCheck function: In this gasprice() function of the inline assembly is used, which also gives the effective gas price for the current transaction, which includes both the base fee and the priority fee.


NOTE: The output from gasprice() should match or closely resemble tx.gasprice, as it represents the actual gas price paid for the transaction, considering both base fee and priority fee.
So, from your example values:

getBaseFee returned 9138656943 (base fee),

getGasPrice returned 10950129256 (base fee + priority fee),

getGasPriceCheck returned 11056634983, which is similar to tx.gasprice but can sometimes reflect subtle variations depending on when each call is made in the block (or due to minor rounding effects in assembly).



Just one question on your explanation of tx.gasprice - you say that This is the max fee per gas set by the user in their wallet or transaction configuration. But this isn't strictly true, as the amount of pirority fee effectively taken is balanced at the time of execution - ergo its not a discrete value but an upper range. So the question is how is this diff (priority fee vs maximum gas) evaluated at execution time?

I think, this answer explains the calculation that you're asking for.

so, tx.gasprice should be almost identical to ...:= gasprice()? Its the same code being called, just one is via assembly which makes the gas cost of calling it slightly different. Right?

Yes exactly. Moreover, the tx.gasprice global variable was not there in the initial versions of Solidity. So, developers had to use the gasprice() function of inline assembly to access the transaction’s gas price.
